# compare file B with A and extract data from A by using awk ,sed or grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files file A which contains all the data while there is another file B which only have the IDs what I want is to compare file B with file A and retrieving the data which is present in that id's. I am using Suse Linux.

**file A**

```
C    02020 Two-component system [PATH:aap02020]
D      NT05HA_1798 sensor protein CpxA  
D      NT05HA_1797 CpxR K07662 cpxR
C    02030 *Bacterial chemotaxis* [PATH:aap02030]
D      NT05HA_0919 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
D      NT05HA_0918 maltose-binding periplasmic protein 
C    03070 *Bacterial secretion system* [PATH:aap03070]
D      NT05HA_1309 protein-export membrane protein SecD 
D      NT05HA_1310 protein-export membrane protein SecF 
D      NT05HA_1819 preprotein translocase subunit SecE
D      NT05HA_1287 protein-export membrane protein  
C    02060 Phosphotransferase system (PTS) [PATH:aap02060]
D      NT05HA_0618 phosphoenolpyruvate-protein 
D      NT05HA_0617 phosphocarrier protein HPr 
D      NT05HA_0619 pts system
```

**file B**

```
Bacterial chemotaxis
Bacterial secretion system
```

**Desired Output:**

```
C    02030 *Bacterial chemotaxis* [PATH:aap02030]
D      NT05HA_0919 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
D      NT05HA_0918 maltose-binding periplasmic protein 
C    03070 *Bacterial secretion system* [PATH:aap03070]
D      NT05HA_1309 protein-export membrane protein SecD
D      NT05HA_1310 protein-export membrane protein SecF
D      NT05HA_1819 preprotein translocase subunit SecE  
D      NT05HA_1287 protein-export membrane protein
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{         # On the first file,
       a[$0];         # store the content in the array a
       next
     } 
     {                        # On the second file, 
         for(i in a)          # for all element in the array a,
            if(index($0,i)) { # check if there is match in the current record
               print "C" $0   # in that case print it with the record separator
               next
            }
     }' fileB RS='\nC' fileA
C    02030 *Bacterial chemotaxis* [PATH:aap02030]
D      NT05HA_0919 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
D      NT05HA_0918 maltose-binding periplasmic protein 
C    03070 *Bacterial secretion system* [PATH:aap03070]
D      NT05HA_1309 protein-export membrane protein SecD 
D      NT05HA_1310 protein-export membrane protein SecF 
D      NT05HA_1819 preprotein translocase subunit SecE
D      NT05HA_1287 protein-export membrane protein
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match exactly on the part that is in between the `C <word>` and `[PATH:...]` (and assuming those `*` in your sample are just for emphasis and not part of the actual data), you could do:

```
awk '
  !start {all_strings[$0]; next}
  /^C/ {
    key = $0

    # strip the leading C <word>:
    sub(/^C[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]*/, "", key)

    # strip the trailing [...]:
    sub(/[[:blank:]]*\[[^]]*][[:blank:]]*$/, "", key)
    selected = key in all_strings
  }
  selected' fileB start=1 fileA
```

Beside the added reliability (for instance `Bacterial secretion` would only match for a `Bacterial secretion` record, and not also for `Bacterial secretion system`), it's also very efficient in that the files are only read once and the matching is only one hash table lookup as opposed to a number of substring searches or regular expression matchings.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure I will get knocked over the head for using a loop, but still... here's one way to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
        sed -n "/$line/,/^C/p" fileA | sed '$d'
        done < fileB
```

Example:

```
./bacteria.sh 
C    02030 *Bacterial chemotaxis* [PATH:aap02030]
D      NT05HA_0919 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
D      NT05HA_0918 maltose-binding periplasmic protein 
C    03070 *Bacterial secretion system* [PATH:aap03070]
D      NT05HA_1309 protein-export membrane protein SecD 
D      NT05HA_1310 protein-export membrane protein SecF 
D      NT05HA_1819 preprotein translocase subunit SecE
D      NT05HA_1287 protein-export membrane protein
```

Where `fileA` and `fileB` are your exemple files.

Regex breakdown:

```
sed -n "/$line/,/^C/p" fileA | sed '$d'
```

Print lines between `$line` and the next line beginning with the letter `C`, but exclude (`sed '$d'`) the final line, since it is used merely as a "stop marker".

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: The `.*` are not needed in the regexp.

Comment: @kmkaplan Of course! You are right. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, this is _extremely_ inefficient like all other answers that use a `while..read` loop (which is famous for its "speed")  and process `fileA` _n_ times where _n_ is the no. of lines in `fileB`.

Comment: @don_crissti What took you so long, I felt stupid sitting here with my helmet on for no apparent reason ;-)

Comment: I'll give you a rap on the knuckles as well for not mentioning the [command injection vulnerability](/a/297128) for when the content of fileB is not fully under your control.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But... the content is under my control, I made it!

Comment: You could also mention that it won't work properly if the lines of fileB contain / or regex operators, and that it assumes there's only one match for each $line

Comment: It might be under your control, or even the OP's control, but maybe not for the next person that comes here with a similar requirement. In any case, it's worth mentioning the risk.

Answer (score 3):

With `grep` and `sed` in one line:

```
for i in $(grep -f fileb filea | awk '{print $2}'); do sed -e 's/^C/\nC/g' filea | sed -n "/$i/,/^ *$/p" | grep -v "^$"; done
```

That is:

Take the patterns to search for with:

```
grep -f fileb filea | awk '{print $2}'
```

Insert a blank line before every line starting by C:

```
sed -e 's/^C/\nC/g' filea
```

Take from pattern to blank line:

```
sed -n "/$i/,/^ *$/p"
```

Delete blank lines in order to get the desired output:

```
grep -v "^$"
```

All this inside a for loop to be able to do the same process for every pattern on fileb.

Answer (score 3):

The data in `fileA` is divided into records that starts with a `C` on a new line.  Each record is divided inte fields that starts with a `D` on a new line.

We need to read the lines from `fileB` and use them to query the first field of each record in `fileA`:

```
while read -r query; do
    awk -vq="$query" 'BEGIN { RS="^C|\nC"; FS=OFS="\nD" } $1 ~ q {print "C" $0}' fileA
done <fileB
```

I'm setting the record separator (`RS`) to match either `C` at the beginning of a line *or* after a newline, or we may not be able to match anything in the first record properly.  I'm using an `awk` variable, `q`, to hold the value read from the file and I match the first field of every record to this value.

Result:

```
C    02030 *Bacterial chemotaxis* [PATH:aap02030]
D      NT05HA_0919 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
D      NT05HA_0918 maltose-binding periplasmic protein
C    03070 *Bacterial secretion system* [PATH:aap03070]
D      NT05HA_1309 protein-export membrane protein SecD
D      NT05HA_1310 protein-export membrane protein SecF
D      NT05HA_1819 preprotein translocase subunit SecE
D      NT05HA_1287 protein-export membrane protein
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution that covers all sizes of your files: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

**EXAMPLE: Grepping n lines for m regular expressions.**

The simplest solution to grep a big file for a lot of regexps is:

```
grep -f regexps.txt bigfile
```

Or if the regexps are fixed strings:

```
grep -F -f regexps.txt bigfile
```

There are 3 limiting factors: CPU, RAM, and disk I/O.

RAM is easy to measure: If the grep process takes up most of your free memory (e.g. when running top), then RAM is a limiting factor.

CPU is also easy to measure: If the grep takes >90% CPU in top, then the CPU is a limiting factor, and parallelization will speed this up.

It is harder to see if disk I/O is the limiting factor, and depending on the disk system it may be faster or slower to parallelize. The only way to know for certain is to test and measure.

**Limiting factor: RAM**

The normal grep -f regexs.txt bigfile works no matter the size of bigfile, but if regexps.txt is so big it cannot fit into memory, then you need to split this.

grep -F takes around 100 bytes of RAM and grep takes about 500 bytes of RAM per 1 byte of regexp. So if regexps.txt is 1% of your RAM, then it may be too big.

If you can convert your regexps into fixed strings do that. E.g. if the lines you are looking for in bigfile all looks like:

```
ID1 foo bar baz Identifier1 quux
fubar ID2 foo bar baz Identifier2
```

then your regexps.txt can be converted from:

```
ID1.*Identifier1
ID2.*Identifier2
```

into:

```
ID1 foo bar baz Identifier1
ID2 foo bar baz Identifier2
```

This way you can use grep -F which takes around 80% less memory and is much faster.

If it still does not fit in memory you can do this:

```
parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block 1M grep -F -f - -n bigfile |
sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
```

The 1M should be your free memory divided by the number of cores and divided by 200 for grep -F and by 1000 for normal grep. On GNU/Linux you can do:

```
free=$(awk '/^((Swap)?Cached|MemFree|Buffers):/ { sum += $2 }
          END { print sum }' /proc/meminfo)
percpu=$((free / 200 / $(parallel --number-of-cores)))k

parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block $percpu --compress grep -F -f - -n bigfile |
sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
```

If you can live with duplicated lines and wrong order, it is faster to do:

```
parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block $percpu --compress grep -F -f - bigfile
```

**Limiting factor: CPU**

If the CPU is the limiting factor parallelization should be done on the regexps:

```
cat regexp.txt | parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin --compress grep -f - -n bigfile |
sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
```

The command will start one grep per CPU and read bigfile one time per CPU, but as that is done in parallel, all reads except the first will be cached in RAM. Depending on the size of regexp.txt it may be faster to use --block 10m instead of -L1000.

Some storage systems perform better when reading multiple chunks in parallel. This is true for some RAID systems and for some network file systems. To parallelize the reading of bigfile:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile -k --compress grep -f regexp.txt
```

This will split bigfile into 100MB chunks and run grep on each of these chunks. To parallelize both reading of bigfile and regexp.txt combine the two using --fifo:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile --fifo cat regexp.txt \
\| parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f - {}
```

If a line matches multiple regexps, the line may be duplicated.

**Bigger problem**

If the problem is too big to be solved by this, you are probably ready for Lucene.

Comment: That is all very interesting but is not what is being asked here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Why do you feel that? This is exactly what is asked: grep for the lines in file B (regexp.txt) in file A (bigfile).

Comment: If you read the question more carefully, the OP wants full records (consisting of C and following D lines) for the records in file A whose C line matches any of the pattern (or more likely contains any of the strings in some particular position, the requirements are unclear I'm extrapolating from the desired output) found in file B

Answer (score 1):

The bash uses only builtins to generate the output. The code logic is pretty elementary & self-explanatory as well.

## Bash

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   IFS=$'\n'; for pat in $(< fileB); do
      case $line in
         [C]*"$pat"* )
            echo "$line"
            unset flag
            break
            ;;

         [D]* )
            ${flag+":"} echo "$line"
            ${flag+":"} break
            ;;

         * ) flag=;;
      esac
   done
done < fileA
```

With GNU sed we load the patterns into hold area and then on fileB data, we compare them to determine to print the C-D+ blocks or not depending on whether a match was found on the C line using the patterns stored in hold.
The fileB should not begin with a C or D.

## Sed

```
sed -e '
   /^D/bD

   /^C/{
      x;G
      /\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}[^\n]*\1[^\n]*$/{
         s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;x
         :loop
            n
         /^C/!bloop
         s/^/\n/;D
      }
      s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;x
      :D
      $!N;D
   }

   H;d
' fileB fileA
```

## Perl

```
perl -l -0777ne '
   push(@A, split $\), next if @ARGV;
   for my $pat ( map { quotemeta } @A ) {
      while ( /^C [^\n]* $pat [^\n]*$/xmg ) {
         my $C = $&;
         print $C .= $& if /\G(\nD.*$)+/xm;
      }
   }
' fileB fileA
```